# How can I operate variable in such a function?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick='new a().add()'>add</button>
<script>
function a() {
 this.count = 0;
 this.add = function() {
  count++;
 }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this demo, I want to click the add button and then make count plus one. But when I click the add button, I get error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined
    at add (test.html:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:4)
```

So I want to ask how to make count plus one in this demo?

Comment: `this.count++;`...

Comment: I do not understand what does “new a()...” means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment `this.count` rather than `count`. `this.count` refers to the property of the object (because [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is the context of the object) where `count` refers to a variable.

```js
var obj = new a()

function a() {
 this.count = 0;
 this.add = function() {
   this.count++;
   console.log(this.count)
 }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='obj.add()'>add</button>
```

Also, initialize the object separately so whenever the `button` is pressed, the count is incremented in the same object rather than another a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Each click creates a new object, calls the add method on the new object, and increases the count of the new object

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="new a().add()">add</button>
    <script>
      let count = (this.count = 0);
      function a() {
        this.add = function() {
          count += 1;
          console.log(count);
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `this.count++`, not `count++`:

```js
var myInstance = new a();

function a() {
  this.count = 0;
  this.add = function() {
    this.count++;
    console.log(this.count);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='myInstance.add()'>add</button>
```